# Is there UK data on the reduction in vaccine effectiveness for people who were vaccinated 5+ months ago?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, united-kingdom

Leaving aside the completely unvaccinated sections of the population (in themselves a huge problem), preliminary data [from Israel](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.08.03.21261496v1) and the US (in selected cohorts [Mayo](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.08.06.21261707v1.full.pdf), [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/70/wr/mm7034e4.htm?s_cid=mm7034e4_w)--on "frontline" workers) concomitantly pointed to a reduction of mRNA vaccine effectiveness in preventing infection and even symptomatic cases (if using a fairly low-threshold def for those as Israel does), which led to the approval of 3rd/booster shots in both countries (insofar with more limited recommendation age-wise in the US than in Israel.)

The closest similar study I could [find](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-02261-8) from the UK, was limited to 90 days after the vaccine though:

> The vaccine made by Pfizer in New York City and BioNTech in Mainz, Germany, was 92% effective at keeping people from developing a high viral load — a high concentration of the virus in their test samples — 14 days after the second dose. But the vaccine’s effectiveness fell to 90%, 85% and 78% after 30, 60 and 90 days, respectively.
>
> The vaccine developed by Oxford and the pharmaceutical company AstraZeneca in Cambridge, UK, was 69% effective against a high viral load 14 days after the second dose, falling to 61% by 90 days.

Given the Israeli data on Pfizer, see e.g. graph below, I don't/didn't expect one to see much of a drop-off after just 90 days, compared to after at least 120 days.

[image]

One preprint from Israel put the statistically significant cutoff [at 146 days](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.08.03.21261496v1.full.pdf+html). A [2nd stduy](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.07.29.21261317v1) even used matched pairs by sex, age, socioeconomic status, and city of residence, still finding a [statistically significant] difference in vaccine effectiveness comparing Jan-Feb vs Mar-April as months of administration.

On the other hand, the US [CDC study](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/70/wr/mm7034e4.htm?s_cid=mm7034e4_w) (only on a working-age cohort, albeit with higher exposure risk) was somewhat inconclusive in that regard:

> The VE point estimate was 85% among participants for whom <120 days had elapsed since completion of full vaccination compared with 73% among those for whom ≥150 days had elapsed; however the VE 95% CI were overlapping, indicating the difference was not statistically significant.

When they used site-specific date cutoffs (this was multi-center study) based on local delta-variant dominance (defined as >50% of cases), there was less overlap, but not quite [statistical] separation:

> Adjusted VE during this Delta predominant period was 66% (95% CI = 26%–84%) compared with 91% (95% CI = 81%–96%) during the months preceding Delta predominance.

Both Israel and the UK [were](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-02-25/how-u-k-and-israel-raced-to-global-lead-in-covid-vaccinations) champions at early vaccine administrations in Feb-Mar, so I expect there's a large enough cohort of 120- or 150+-days-since-vaccination in the UK to study as well.

So, is there any data from the UK, no matter how preliminary, on the effectiveness of vaccines at 5+ months (150+ days) since 2nd-dose administration? (In particular, Astra Zeneca data would be most interesting in that regard, since this vaccine was not used in the US and Israel, but it's considered a great hope for the less developed countries, due to price, storage conditions etc.)